# Anyone has (android) adb runing on embedded linux for tethering?

Tags: android, linux, arm, adb

I have an arm device running linux, I've tried cross compile adb to arm, it runs and everything, but when I do adb devices, it gives me an empty list. When I plug the phone into the usb port, linux does recognized that it is an HTC phone and it gives the serial number of the phone also, so I think linux/usb is working, but adb won't pick up the phone. I want to do tethering on the arm device using an android phone, but I'm now stuck. FYI, I've also try the same thing on a desktop running ubuntu and it worked. BTW, the arm device is mini2440. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: is usb debugging enabled on the phone?

Comment: Yeah, I've checked that and I did everything as root on the device, so the permission is not an issue.

Comment: did you try killing and restarting adb?

Comment: also did you properly edit your udev rules file too?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you got adb compiled the right way?  There's a lot of code that's used for both the device and the host, and your cross compilation may have confused that mechanism causing it not to build usb transport support.  That said, are you sure it's adb and not some kind of network-over-usb interface that you need for tethering?

Comment: Kevin: Yeah, I kill and start so many times but, same thing. Since I was do everything as root, I don't think the udev rules matters, the fact is, I don't even have udev on the device, it's running mdev.

Comment: Chris: You've pointed out the 1 thing that I was worrying about, I'm not so sure that my cross compile adb is working like it should, but then I don't know what adb is doing internally, so I don't even know what else I could check. One thing I'm looking into right now is the folder that usb mounts on. On the device, it mounts on /proc/bus/usb, where as on the desktop, it mounts on /dev/bus/usb. I'm not sure whether adb would scan /proc/bus/ for usb.

Comment: So I finally had it working, the problem was the path. Adb scans on /dev/bus/usb, I have to change it to /proc/bus/usb for adb to work.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't played around with Linux on Android, but to connect a phone to ADB on a pc you need to add a rule in your udev.

I'm running Debian, I have

`#htc
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", OWNER="jack", GROUP="jack"`

`#motorola
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666", OWNER="jack", GROUP="jack"`

`#lg
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", OWNER="jack", GROUP="jack"`

`#samsung
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", OWNER="jack", GROUP="jack"`

saved as `/etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules`

I got the vendor id's from lsusb. After making changes to the file I restart udev

`udevadm control --reload-rules`

This could be totally wrong or different on Android, have yet to try it. But maybe your solution is something similar.

Comment: Klau solved the actual problem almost a year ago - it was a path issue not a permission one.  It's not clear that this desktop linux mechanism even exists on the embedded device in question - while the adb program would need access, there are many ways to achieve that which are appropriate for different installations.